# When document.getElementByID is used without an ID what is it doing?

Tags: javascript, dom, getelementbyid

I have some code I am looking at that is using a variation on getElementByID that I do not understand. I have looked online but I am not finding anything that explains this.

I understand how to use something like document.getElementByID("bob"), however what I am looking at says:

```
if (document.getElementByID){}
```

When you use getElementByID in this fashion what is it doing?

Comment: It's `getElementById` not `getElementByID`

Comment: It's checking for the presence of the method on document.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`document.getElementById` returns the function which can be used to get some element by ID.

```
typeof document.getElementById; // 'function'
```

However, if some browser didn't implement `getElementById`, you would get `undefined`.

Therefore, this is just a test to ensure that the method exists before calling it, avoiding an error.

```
if(document.getElementById) {
  // Hopefully it's safe to call it
  document.getElementById("bob");
  // ...
} else {
  alert('What kind of stupid browser are you using? Install a proper one');
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that answers the question and makes sense in context :-)

Answer (score 1):

This will return `false`:

```
if (document.getElementByID){}
```

because there is no `getElementByID` on the `document` object. There is however, `getElementById` (notice the difference in the `d` at the end).

Therefore, this will return `true`

```
if (document.getElementById){}
```

In short, if `getElementByID` exists on document, which because of the typing, does not, but if it did then do something.

A more full example using the right spelling:

```
if (document.getElementById) {
    // it is safe to use this method because it exists on document
    var element = document.getElementById('foo');
}
```

`document.getElementById` returns a function which evaluates to `true` when in an expression. You can test this out yourself but running the code snippet.

```js
console.log(document.getElementById);
// The !! forces a boolean
console.log(!!document.getElementById);
```